# modify array of objects - javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this.

```
[
    {KEY1: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE2", PID: "VALUE36"}
    {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE2", PID: "VALUE47"}
    {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE4", PID: "VALUE49"}
    {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE4", PID: "VALUE43"}
]
```

I need a data-structure like this. So basically the `key NAME` which has duplicate names will become key in new data-structure. And `key PID` will be its value in an array.

```
[
   { VALUE2: [VALUE36, VALUE47] },
   { VALUE4: [VALUE49, VALUE43] },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe modfied.

Comment: ...same question

Comment: Where is the code you've attempted to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregation like this be handled by [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). For example:

```js
const arr = [
  {KEY1: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE2", PID: "VALUE36"},
  {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE2", PID: "VALUE47"},
  {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE4", PID: "VALUE49"},
  {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE4", PID: "VALUE43"},
]

// Objects are basically associative arrays in JS, so...
// (For each item in arr, add or update an array at obj[item.NAME])
const obj = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
  const val = [ item.PID ]
  obj[item.NAME] = Array.isArray(obj[item.NAME])
    ? obj[item.NAME].concat(val)
    : val
  return obj
}, {}) // start with obj = {}

/*
At this point, we have
obj = {
  "VALUE2": [
    "VALUE36",
    "VALUE47"
  ],
  "VALUE4": [
    "VALUE49",
    "VALUE43"
  ]
}
*/

// ...but since you specified separate objects, this finishes it off
const newArr = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, val]) => ({ [key]: val }))
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: I personally learned through trial-and-error (and trying to answer StackOverflow questions) but MDN is usually a great resource. Maybe start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics?

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [
    {KEY1: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE2", PID: "VALUE36"},
    {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE2", PID: "VALUE47"},
    {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE4", PID: "VALUE49"},
    {KEY11: "VALUE1", NAME: "VALUE4", PID: "VALUE43"},
];

var b = [];
a.forEach(function(element) {
  if (b[element['NAME']] === undefined) {
    b[element['NAME']] = [];
  }
  b[element['NAME']].push(element['PID']);
});

console.log(b);
```

Output:

```
[ VALUE2: [ 'VALUE36', 'VALUE47' ], VALUE4: [ 'VALUE49', 'VALUE43' ] ]
```